# Excel how to get the last 8 charcters string from another Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Sheet 4,

Now i can output Column D in Sheet 4
From Column L in Sheet 1

For example, take D4 in Sheet 4, it'll get L4 in Sheet 1
using

```
=IF(Sheet1!L4<>"",Sheet1!L4,"")
```

In sheet 4, i  want to get only the last 8 characters in Column L from sheet 1
im trying to use `RIGHT(text, [num_chars])`

=IF(RIGHT(Sheet1!L4<>"", L,8),RIGHT(Sheet1!L4<>"", L,8))

But it fails to work.

Any thought? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(Sheet1!L4<>"",RIGHT(Sheet1!L4, 8),"")
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice here.

Comment: Tim’s answer shows the correct application of the functions already chosen by the OP - not much explanation needed except removing the extra argument in right() that does not exist.